# Powershell function not receiving parameters

Tags: powershell, parameters, arguments

I have a Powershell script. My ultimate goal is to compare the two Excel files and highlight differences in both versions. Part of my "preparatory code" is this:

```
    function DefineVars () {
        Clear-Host

        # Define some basic variables
        $Directory = Split-Path -Parent $PSCommandPath
        $FilePath = $Directory + "\xlsx\"
        $FileName1 = $FilePath + "Firewallv2.xlsx"
        $FileName2 = $FilePath + "Firewallv3.xlsx"
        $OutFile1 = $FilePath + "file1_raw.csv"
        $OutFile2 = $FilePath + "file2_raw.csv"

        # Create an Object Excel.Application using Com interface
        $Excel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
        $Excel.Visible = $false
        $Excel.DisplayAlerts = $false

        # Generate the Workbook Objects
        $WorkBook1 = $Excel.Workbooks.Open($FileName1)
        $WorkBook2 = $Excel.Workbooks.Open($FileName2)

        return $Directory, $FilePath, $FileName1, $FileName2, $OutFile1, $OutFile2, $Excel, $WorkBook1, $WorkBook2

    }

    function GenerateData ($WorkBook, $OutFile) {

        $Results = @()
        Write-Host $OutFile

        foreach ($CurrentWorkSheet in $WorkBook.Worksheets) {

            $CurrentWorkSheetName = $CurrentWorkSheet.Name
            $CurrentWorkSheetRows = $CurrentWorkSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
            $CurrentWorkSheetColumns = $CurrentWorkSheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count

            $CurrentWorkSheet.Activate()

            for ($CurrentColumn = 1; $CurrentColumn -le $CurrentWorkSheetColumns; $CurrentColumn++) {

                for ($CurrentRow = 1; $CurrentRow -le $CurrentWorkSheetRows; $CurrentRow++) {

                    $CurrentCell = $CurrentWorksheet.Cells.Item($CurrentRow, $CurrentColumn)
                    $CurrentCellContent = $CurrentCell.Text

                    if ([System.IO.File]::Exists($OutFile)) {

                        Write-Host "true"
                        #","+$CurrentCellContent | Out-File $OutFile -Append

                    } else {

                        Write-Host "false"
                        #$CurrentCellContent | Out-File $OutFile

                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return $Results
    }

    function CloseExcel () {

    $WorkBook1.Close($true)
    $WorkBook2.Close($true)
    $Excel.Quit()
    spps -n Excel

    }

$Directory, $FilePath, $FileName1, $FileName2, $OutFile1, $OutFile2, $Excel, $WorkBook1, $WorkBook2 = DefineVars

$ResultsFile1 = GenerateData($WorkBook1, $OutFile1)
$ResultsFile2 = GenerateData($WorkBook2, $OutFile2)
CloseExcel
```

My problem is that the parameter call to the GenerateData functions of the $OutFile variables won't work for some reason. All the other parameters appear to be passed successfully, e.g. the WorkBooks. But if I insert a `Write-Host $OutFile` at the beginning of the GenerateData function, the string is empty (which means it doesn't get passed, if I am not mistaken).

I am sure this is easily explained, but I just can't seem to figure this one out.

Thanks and best

Simon

Answer (score 0):

I got it. My problem was the syntax in the main method. Being caught up in other languages, I thought I needed parentheses and commas to pass arguments. Yet, it's much simpler with Powershell:

```
$ResultsFile1 = GenerateData $WorkBook1 $OutFile1
$ResultsFile2 = GenerateData $WorkBook2 $OutFile2
CompareObjects $ResultsFile1 $ResultsFile2
CloseExcel
```

This did the trick! The only weird thing about it is that Powershell doesn't throw an error, if you stick to the parentheses-comma style of coding. The argument simply doesn't get passed.